# Loop on my redirection page when the target has a redirection loop

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a redirection page to an external website which does

```
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.replace($('#js-data-redirect').data('url'));
            }, 1500);
```

It works very good, but right now the external website is down and has a redirection loop (301 on himself). The problem is that I makes loop my page : it refreshes every 1500ms...

Have you experienced that ?

I guess the solution is to have a ajax HEAD request during the redirection waiting time and not redirect if failure.

I will try to reproduce the loop behaviour locally

Comment: Yes, that sounds like something I'd do. I'd probably do the AJAX call as early as possible to know in advance whether I should try to redirect or not in advance.